# Django - permanent connection to external database

Tags: python, django, database-connection

While iteration adding records to a local database I need to connect to an external database to import the data. It takes quite a long time. I get the impression that the reason is creating a new connection during each loop iteration. Does it possible to set the connection to an external database permanently?

```
def setup_cursor():
    try:
        cursor = connections['legacy'].cursor()
        return cursor
    except ConnectionDoesNotExist:
        print "Legacy database is not configured"
        return None


def make_query(sql):
    cursor = setup_cursor()
    if cursor is None:
        return
    cursor.execute(sql)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    if rows is None:
        return
    return rows

def get_external_data(var):
    sql = "...."
    result = make_query(sql.format(var))
    return result

# adding records to local db
for x in y:
    add_row = SomeModel (field1=xxx, field2=get_external_data(var))
    add_row.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `CON_MAX_AGE` to `None` in your database settings.

> Persistent connections
>
> The default value is 0, preserving the historical behavior of closing
>   the database connection at the end of each request. To enable
>   persistent connections, set CONN_MAX_AGE to a positive number of
>   seconds. For unlimited persistent connections, set it to None.

**E.g** :

```python
DATABASES = {
    'legacy': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': None,
    }
}
```

Here is a class that should do the job :

```python
class LegacyDatabase(object):
    cursor = None

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.cursor = connections['legacy'].cursor()
        except ConnectionDoesNotExist:
            print "Legacy database is not configured"

    def query(self, param):
        query = 'your query'
        if self.cursor:
            self.cursor.execute(query.format(param))
            return self.cursor.fetchall()
```

now use `db.query(param)` in your code to query your legacy database.
 **E.g** :

```python
db = LegacyDatabase()
# adding records to local db
for x in y:
    add_row = SomeModel (field1=xxx, field2=db.query(param))
    add_row.save()
```

Read [Django documentation - conn-max-age](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.9/ref/settings/#conn-max-age) for more information

Comment: after this change it takes 10 times longer

Comment: That an other problem. Yeah, I strange since the connection is persistent but maybe the problem come from your code. Despite that, here is how you can enable persistent connections between your app and your database. Search in your code to find what its longer.

Comment: Fragment which I pasted is correct? `cursor = setup_cursor()` doesn't create new connection on each call?

Comment: Of course yes. I haven't all your script but it seems that you create persistent connection at each call that why it's slower. Setup only one time connection and get this connection at each call

Comment: And this is my question. How to do that?

Comment: That's an other question then update your question with your all code

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think, I wrote it in the first post, in slightly different words: "I get the impression that the reason is creating a new connection during each loop iteration. Does it possible to set the connection to an external database permanently?".

This is all necessary code. Connection, query and insert records.